# How do I migrate DNS from DO to Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'd like to move our DNS management from DO to AWS.

I've updated the DNS on the DO to point to AWS Route 53 nameservers and added the records on route 53 in preparation.

After setting the NS records for the domain, it seems like it hasn't yet propagated. My experience has been that DNS changes typically take a couple of minutes, unless I've made a mistake somewhere (albeit often it's said that it can take between 24-48 hours).

After running some dig commands, it seems like the NS records are still pointing to digital ocean.

Should I have made additional changes to get this to work?

Comment: Hello assuming you have added all NS Of aws in Do generally it only takes few minutes , more information would be required on this , also can you can contact Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 1):

Where is your domain "registered"? You'll probably want to change the NS records in Route53 (as it seems like you've done already), but you'll also need to change them with your domain registrar who ultimately defines your name servers. So, if it's registered in Route53, then you'll need to go in to Route53 -> Registered domains and you'll see "Name servers" in there - they'll be pointing to your old name servers I suspect. If it's not Route53 where you've got your domain registered, it'll be a similar process whether your domain is registered with Gandi, GoDaddy, 1&1, eNom or wherever.

Comment: I've done this already, seemed like it just needed a while to propagate.